# c# waiting for a Task

Tags: c#, task

In my enterprise application I need to check the existence of a file (mostly over network) each 800ms. The current method, which works fine is this:

```
private delegate bool FileExistsDelegate(string file);
public static bool FileExists(string path, int timeout = 2000)
{
    bool retValue = false;
    try
    {
        FileExistsDelegate callback = new FileExistsDelegate(File.Exists);
        IAsyncResult result = callback.BeginInvoke(path, null, null);
        if (result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(timeout, false))
            return callback.EndInvoke(result);
        return false;
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The problem is that freeze the UI if no path is found, so I rewrited it using the Task as:

```
public static bool FileExists(string path, int timeout = 2000)
{
    Func<bool> func = () => File.Exists(path);
    Task<bool> task = new Task<bool>(func);
    task.Start();
    if (task.Wait(timeout))
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

The problem is that my task doesn't wait as expected, seems that timeout is not used. Is this approach correct about using Task/Wait? The format of file is like "\\10.100.100.1\status.txt"

Comment: What UI are you using? Have you considered a background worker?

Comment: `return Task.Wait(timeout) && task.Result` is probably what you want. I guess you want to know if the file exists?

Comment: Mikael Dúi Bolinder, yes correct. I will try

Comment: @OttoVasken first off all you should use ```await```.

Comment: @MikaelDúiBolinder it works like a charm, thank you

Comment: @OttoVasken I've added it as an answer then. You should update the Title of your Question to a more descriptive one. Your title says very little about the question.

Comment: Why are you not using async functions?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You're not returning the `Result` of the `Task`.

```
public static bool FileExists(string path, int timeout = 2000)
{
    Task<bool> task = Task.Run(() => File.Exists(path));
    return task.Wait(timeout)) && task.Result;
}
```

- Returns `false` if the `Task`fails or if the `Result` is `false`.
- Returns `true` if the `Task` is successful and if the `Result` is
  `true`.